# Ag-grid Angular Material Datepicker on Cell Editor lose focus when clicking on date picker

Tags: angular, angular-material, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am making a room reservation app on Ag-grid. Please check
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-datepicker?file=src/app/reservation-management/reservation-management.component.ts)
From date and to date columns represent check in date and check out date. The columns are set as Cell Editor and using Angular Material Datepicker as Calendar. But After double clicking on date cell and date picker pops up. The date picker closes whenever left clicks on a date or any button on the picker and no value is returned.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like a bug in ag grid. please, update it to at least 23 version in your package.json

```
    "ag-grid-angular": "^23.0.1",
    "ag-grid-community": "^23.0.1",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^23.0.1",
```

Comment: Would be any issue if just change from 21 to 23, since this is not new angular project and reservation component is just one of many components.

Comment: i see this upgrade as the easiest solution. making a workaround would require a lot of work, if it is even possible

Comment: i can reproduce the case with ag grid version 26.2